# Получение открытых вкладок браузера Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Есть расширение хрома с `backgroun` страницей. У человека в браузере открыто пару вкладок. Нужно с помощью `background` страницы получить ссылки на страницы открытые в других вкладках.
А если возможно получть весь DOM каждой из открытых страниц.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно разрешение "tabs" в манифесте расширения.

```js
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
   for (var tab of tabs) {
      console.log(tab.url);
   }
})
```

Можно только узнать адреса ссылок, а доступ к DOM есть только у content script.